# Unable to show movie using html <video> tag

Tags: html, video, large-files

I am trying to show movie using `<video>` tag of HTML. I think I have done everything right but video is not playing.

```
 <video width="640" src="../Movies/Ice Age/Ice Age Dawn Of The Dinosaurs (2009) [1080p]/Ice.Age.Dawn.Of.The.Dinosaurs.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="images.jfif" preload="metadata" onplay="playing()" controls>Video tag is not supported.</video>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what's not working.

Comment: Showing play option but not able to play video.

Answer (score -1):

```
   <video width="400" controls>
       <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
```

Hi try like this

Comment: I have played video with the style preciously I have written and it worked.